# How to save different faceIDs in my app using iPhone X and match them later with any face - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, face-recognition, iphone-x, face-id

I want to first save FaceIDs through my app and then I want to match different faceIDs from those I have saved. Any solution for it?

Apple does provide this:

FaceID:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: "Face IDs are not reused, and the same face leaving and entering the picture again is assigned a new identifier." The documentation tells you cannot do it.

Comment: Alright... Thanks!